numpy.random.randn generates the same values every time
My code is very basic
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
X_assess = np.random.randn(2, 3)
Y_assess = (np.random.randn(1, 3) > 0)
print (X_assess)
print (Y_assess)

However, it generates the same value every time I execute this code. (I am using https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_numpy_online.php)
The values are

Any idea why? I thought that the values will be random and will differ every execution.

This is the purpose of np.random.seed(1) to configure the RNG to get the same value after that... But each value will be different (at least this is very unlikely for this to happen though it can).

The purpose of setting a np.random.seed(seed_value) is so you can get the same answer each time your seed_value is the same. It is meant to say have a unit test where you need your randoms numbers to behave the same way each time.
So much so that you can ship the code and if the seed_value is the same you will get the same answer. I get the exact same numbers here on my machine running python 3.12
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: np.random.seed(1)
   ...: X_assess = np.random.randn(2, 3)
   ...: Y_assess = (np.random.randn(1, 3) > 0)
   ...: print (X_assess)
   ...: print (Y_assess)
[[ 1.62434536 -0.61175641 -0.52817175]
 [-1.07296862  0.86540763 -2.3015387 ]]
[[ True False  True]]


Thank you. I guess it was quite silly of me :)

The reason it's generating the same value every time you execute this code is because you set a seed for the random, when you set a specific seed, the random generator will become deterministic and always generate the same sequence of numbers. Just remove the np.random.seed(1). Here is an example:
import numpy as np

X_assess = np.random.randn(2, 3)
Y_assess = (np.random.randn(1, 3) > 0)
print (X_assess)
print (Y_assess)

